# Eclipse indigo workspace is empty even after switching the workspace to the old one. How to import all of my old projects?

Tags: eclipse, workspace

I did a MacOSX Mountain Lion fresh install.

After restoring my backed up eclipse and workspace folders I'm trying to display all my projects in package explorer to no avail.

Some suggest to import them, but when I try to import via

> File-import-general-existing projects into workspace

I get

> No projects are found to import

I've also tried switching the workbench via

> File-switch workspace-other

but it does not pick any of my old projects that way either.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the projects still have the `.project` file. Since it starts with a dot it may be handled differently when doing a backup, i.e being ignored. 
Also that Eclipse doesnt find any projects also suggests this could be an issue.

Comment: I've got a file called project but no .project . Here is the screenshot http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/213/grabsm.jpg/. I didn't export these folders i just copied the whole workspace folder. No one seems to know the solution for this.